# What's the best way to create a file with application errors?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse RCP application and I want to report bugs on the application, but not for the user, I want to find the root of any possible failure.

What is the recomendation?

I think a logger like log4j is good option, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Logging is a pretty standard way to track the runtime state of an application and aide in debugging, so yeah its a good idea to write log messages at key points during runtime. log4j is a decent logging API.

Comment: You may already know this, but be sure to include the originating exception.  The two banes of my existence are `catch(Exception e){log.error("Got an error doing X " + e.getMessage());}` and `catch(Exception e){throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());}`  Instead always wrap, e.g. `catch(Exception e){log.error("Got an error doing X ", e);}` and `catch(Exception e){throw new RuntimeException(e);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse has some simple logging support accessed via `Plugin.getLog()` or `Platform.getLog(Bundle)`. It is intended mainly for reporting errors so does not have logging levels.

This writes to the `.log` file in the `.metadata` directory of the workspace.